# Lambda Provisioned Concurrency Init Duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have enabled provisioned concurrency (5 units) on one of my lambda functions which is invoked via API Gateway requests.

My impression of this was that it eliminates "cold starts" or "inits" altogether yet when I hit my appropriate Api endpoint after an "idle period" X-Ray & Cloudwatch show me what I would have thought is a cold start?

Init Duration: 2379.57 ms

Subsequent requests don't have this and my total time for the request goes from approx 3.8s to approx 200ms.

My understanding was that provisioning the concurrency would automatically hit the provisioned ones first and thus ALWAYS produce that latter 200ms scenario (assuming we are not exceeding concurrency count). I've created a separate lambda and am the only one using it so I know that is not the issue. I've created an alias, which point to to a version, not $LATEST.

Lambda metrics display "Invocations" "ProvisionedConcurrencyInvocations" with the appropriate colour on the chart which indicated provisioned concurrency.

Why am I getting what is seemingly a cold start still?

If all the above seems OK and my understanding is indeed what should be happening then would it be related to the services used in the lambda itself?

I use S3, SQS and DynamoDB.
Lambda is a c# .net core 3.1 function

**Edit #1 -**

I Should clarify that the function is actually an asp.net core 3.1 web api serverless and has all the usual attached ConfigureServices/Configure points as well as Controller classes.

I have timed and written to console the times it takes to ConfigureServices/Configure and Constructor of the controller. Times are .6s/0.0s/0.0s at first run.

I have enabled XRay at the SDK level in Startup.cs with:

```
AWSSDKHandler.RegisterXRayForAllServices();
```

I can now see the following breakdown in X-Ray:

[image: Cold Start]

And after a few (quick) executions I see:

[image: Already Loaded]

I want to have EVERY single execution sitting at that 163ms and bypass the nearly 4s entirely.

Comment: Make sure you've done all the init work you can *before* handling the actual call.  Especially make sure you've created the DyamoDB client, and that all your classes are ready to go.  Use an instance method as your lambda handler and instantiate all the classes you need to call in the constructor.

Comment: I should have mentioned here Matt that the Lambda Function is actually an asp.net core web api application/Web Api Controller and not a "standard" Lambda. So it has a range of builder functions, service registrations etc. and then the controller functions. How would this effect your previous comment, given the new information?

Comment: Hmm..  I don't do asp.net so I'm not sure.  Just remember that provisioning your concurrent instance is just initialization -- it's only the stuff required for the lambda runtime to get an instance of your handler.  Everything that happens when the handler is called makes an invocation wait for it, and this is probably the 2.4 second delay you're seeing.  Usually that's loading and setting up classes and stuff.

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution to this problem, I'm also experiencing it but in NodeJS